# Modify fit or function to match certain values

Tags: python, curve-fitting, function

I have following values:

```
x = [0, 12.5, 25, 50, 75, 87.5, 100]
y = [0.0, 0.2, 0.31, 0.5, 0.66, 0.76, 1.0]
```

These values represent display values from a device that provides something like a charging status. My problem is that the display (which is a mechanical hand) is not providing the correct values. When everything is correct, it should be a straight linear curve (`x` against `x`). But what I see is `y` against `x`.
What I would like to do: How can I create a function that takes into account these values and provides the correct valuse I would like to have?
My idea is: Fit the measured values and create a function which shifts the data points such that they ly on a straight line, finally.

Does that make sense?

Goal: How do I get the correct values? It looks like I have to shift the values below 50 % downwards and the values above 50 % upwards.

[image: function]

Comment: So what is your question again?

Comment: Finally, how do I get the correct values?

Comment: Is it possible to obtain more data (for example, a finer grid for `x` values)? Do you always get `x = 12.5` when `y = 0.2`?

Comment: Yes, always the same. Isn't just an inverse function doing the job? So I fit the data and then I use the inverse of it.

Comment: In statistics, the measurement error is sometimes random so its' not guaranteed that you always get the same value.

Comment: But I do measure it. The uncertainties are quite small.

Answer (score 1):

If you can measure $y$ for all values of $x$, then you're done...

From the comments above, when there's no uncertainty, there's no need to "fit" any curve. What you have is a function $y = f(x)$ where $y$ is what you're measuring. To get $x$ from this, you simply take the inverse function $x = f^{-1}(y)$, where $f^{-1}$ could be as simple as a piecewise function, for example, $f^{-1}(0.2) = 12.5$

If you cannot measure $y$ for all values of $x$, you could interpolate using [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) ([Python reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scatterplot, the data seemed to me as if it were similar to a sine wave plus a straight line. I fitted the data to several trigonometric functions of this type, and found that a hyperbolic cosine (cosh) with linear growth appears to fit the data well. The below equation and three fitted parameter values yield R-squared = 0.9978 and RMSE): 0.0149

```
amplitude = 8.6803997548024585E-03
center = 7.3734550922795378E+01
width = 1.5909052889748179E+02

pi = 3.14159265358979323846

y = amplitude * cosh(pi * (x - center) / width) * x
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I forgot to mention that the fitted parameter "width" should be the wavelength.

Comment: thanks, but how does this provide the "correct" values?

Comment: The difference between your fitted straight line and this hyperbolic cosine *is* the correction factor you are looking for.

Comment: The line is not fitted, it represents how the correct function should look like.